# How can I set a specific background color on Sublime Text?

Tags: colors, text-editors, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

Note, I don't want to change or set another Color Scheme. I just want to specify the precise color (R,G,B in Hex) I want for the background (or any part of the sublime window). Is that possible? I have found .cache files about each color scheme inside the appdata/local/sublime text 3 directory (Windows) but these are binary files. I thought that they would contain specific settings that I could modify to my liking. But I suppose I have to convert them to text first. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To view Theme files for ST3, install [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) via [PackageControl](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

Then, you can use the `Ctrl + Shift + P >> PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` to view theme files.

To edit a specific background color, you need to create a new file in your user settings with the same name as the theme currently applied to your sublime text file.

1. Create a new file in `Packages/User/SublimeLinter` with the same name as the theme. (Note, if your theme is a 3rd party package installed via package control, you can edit the hex value in that file directly, under background)
2. Otherwise, if you are trying to modify a native sublime theme, Add this to the new file with your color choice

---

```
{
  "globals":
  {
      "background": "rgb(5,5,5)"
  }
}
```

If you are wanting to edit the background color of the sidebar to be darker, go to `Preferences > Theme > Adaptive.sublime-theme`